# Are there any avatars of Devi mentioned in Vedas but not in scriptures(e.g. puranas) and vice versa

Tags: avatars, devi

Are there any avatars of Devi which are not mentioned in Vedas but there is a mention of them in puranas. Also are there any avatars, which are not a part of puranas and itihasas but in shrutis(Vedas, upanishads) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did Lord Shiva take 44 avatars if his primary role is to be the destroyer?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/why-did-lord-shiva-take-44-avatars-if-his-primary-role-is-to-be-the-destroyer)

Comment: I don't think this question is limited to Shiva ,so it cannot be termed as duplicate , but yeah may be too broad to answer.

Comment: In addition to the answer to the  question mentioned above, another answer should be written covering avatars of other Gods.

Comment: @Tezz I ahve a question on Yakeshwara.Y is he called after his species? I mean, avatars like Krishna n Rama are not named "Manava", rite?

Comment: @Tezz oso,like sree charan mentioned, do h know abt avatars of other gods?

Comment: @KVickneshvara Why don't u ask two separate questions--one on Devi and one on Ganesha?

Comment: @K Vickneshvara Yakeshwara incarnation is of special importance because the Gods didn't know who was that Yaksha.. they thought him as normal and boasted before him... so, that incarnation is named as Yaksheswara... yes, Vedas also hint of Hayagriva, Vamana, Matsya etc... incarnation of Vishnu,; Katyayani, Kanyakumari, Girisuta etc.. incarnation of Devi etc...

Comment: @Tezz O...k tq!

Comment: @Tezz Also,who is Girisuta?Ganesha?Giri means Parvati and Suta means son right?

Comment: @Tezz O...Cld u post an answer for Devi plz?

Comment: @Tezz Please post that as an answer

Comment: @K Vickneshvara do you mean I should make an answer like [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/why-did-lord-shiva-take-44-avatars-if-his-primary-role-is-to-be-the-destroyer/16687#16687) seperating incarnations from Smritis and Shrutis?...

Comment: @Tezz Yes please

Comment: @Tezz Hi sorry to bother you, but I think that you might have forgotten to post an answer. I would really appreciate if you could possibly post one. Sry again

Answer (score 1):

Rig Veda mentions many female deities. Ushas is the most celebrated goddess along with Aditi, Prithvi, Rathri, Sarasvathi and Vac.The female deities in Rig Veda form the basis for the emergence of the later goddesses such as Shakthi, Devi and other mother goddesses glorified in the puranas. I think some of Rig Vedic deities are not dealt in puranas elaborately.

In the Rig Veda the goddess Usha is consistently associated with and often identified with the dawn. She reveals herself in the daily coming of light to the world. She has been described in the Rig Veda as a young maiden drawn by one hundred horses. She brings forth light and is followed by the sun who urges her onwards. She is praised for driving away, or is petitioned to drive away, the oppressive darkness. She is asked to chase away evil demons. As the dawn she is said to rouse all life, to set all things in motion and to send people off to do their duties. She sends the curled-up sleepers on their way to offer their sacrifices and thus render service to the other gods.

Another goddess commonly referred to in the Rig Veda is the goddess Prithvi who is nearly always associated with the earth, the terrestrial sphere where human beings live. In the Rig Veda furthermore she is always coupled with Dyaus the male deity associated with the sky. So dependent are these two deities in the Rig Veda that Prithvi is rarely addressed alone but almost always as part of the dual compound Dyaus-Prithvi, Sky-Earth. Together they are said to kiss the centre of the world. They sanctify each other in their complementary relationship. Together they are said to be the universal parents who created the world and the gods. As might be expected, Dyaus is often called 'father' and Prithvi 'mother'.

[Reference](http://www.yogamag.net/archives/1991/ajan91/vedgod.shtml)