# Why did Lord Shiva never take birth in human form as Lord Vishnu has?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, birth

Over the 3 yugas that have passed, we have seen Lord Vishnu take birth in human form (as Ram, Krishna etc.).

We all know how Kalyug is going to end - with the bad being wiped out from this world by Kalki (10th avatar of Lord Vishnu). As Lord Shiva is considered as the destroyer, why won't he manifest in human form and carry out this task?

Comment: You have to see this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/why-did-lord-shiva-take-44-avatars-if-his-primary-role-is-to-be-the-destroyer/16687#16687